# Which plot should be used for dataframe containing multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 1000+ entries.

```
session_id  CategoriesViewed    productsViewed  totalclicks
7.0             2                     16           28.0
8.0             3                      7            9.0
9.0             3                      3            4.0
11.0            1                      2            2.0
15.0            3                      4            4.0
and so on...
```

I am not able to plot a graph to co-relate these values. Is there any plot where I can add all the column's at once and understand (I don't want to use a bubble chart).

Comment: Look into [seaborn's pairplot method](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html). Basically: `import seaborn as sns; sns.pairplot(data)`.

Comment: might want to use stacked bar chart http://6.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/img/Samples/sample-3d-stacked-column-chart.png

Comment: @Abdou i tried running by the method you told. `import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
data = sns.load_dataset("a_df")
g = sns.pairplot(data,vars=["LeafCatCount", "prodCount","totalclicks"]) but got an error `CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2`

Comment: @SRingne You don't need to `load` the dataframe, since it's _your_ dataframe. The only reason the tutorial loads the `iris` dataframe is because it's not available by default. So just do: `sns.pairplot(a_df,vars=["LeafCatCount", "prodCount","totalclicks"])`.

Comment: Maybe a heatmap of the df.corr() would be interesting too: `sns.heatmap(a_df.corr())`